# Cannot control rows properties in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, row

I'm trying to freeze the first column and row of a `DataGridView`. Actually I can freeze the column but not the row. In fact, I can't modify any of row's properties.

I created the table row by row like this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

DataRow workrow;
workrow = table.NewRow();
table.Rows.Add(workrow);
DataColumn column;
column = new DataColumn();
table.Columns.Add(column);

workrow[0] = " mystring ";
```

and then

```
dataGridView3.Columns[0].Frozen = true;
dataGridView3.Rows[0].Frozen = true;
```

The column is frozen but not the row.

It seems that i can't control only the rows.
for exemple : dataGridView3.Rows[0].DividerHeight don't work neither.

Comment: Aren't you trying to freeze the first row of a different gridview?

Comment: change `dataGridView.Rows[0].Frozen = true;`
to `dataGridView3.Rows[0].Frozen = true;`

Comment: i'ts just a typo here. I'm trying to freeze a row and a column in the same datagridview. And it seems that i can't control the rows.dataGridView3.Rows[0].DividerHeight don't work neither.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is where you have to be a hawk, my guess is that intellisense got you on this one.

You are actually calling dataGridView rows, rather than dataGridView3 rows.

```
dataGridView3.Columns[0].Frozen = true;
dataGridView.Rows[0].Frozen = true;
```

Should be

```
dataGridView3.Columns[0].Frozen = true;
dataGridView3.Rows[0].Frozen = true;
```

*Watch your typo's, they come back to haunt you*

Over more in the future I would suggest that you use breakpoints whilst debugging to find out *where you went wrong*, this will allow you to iron out any faults and make it easier to identify what's going wrong!

Comment: I'm sorry but what i had the correct syntax in my code. 

dataGridView3.Columns[0].Frozen = true;
dataGridView3.Rows[0].Frozen = true;

I reviewed my code times and times the week before and i couldn't find a similar problem on the net.
your help is welcome.

Comment: Are you sure? The code you have gave us is not the same as what your telling us now.

Comment: Yes i'm sure i've just corrected the typo i made on the post.

Comment: I've just found the solution with some help. The rows properties must be modified from the parent class. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I solved some of my problems by doing the modifications on the rows from the parent class. It seems to be a bug.